# Orientation is shown wrong while rotating device Google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, media-queries, device-orientation

I have a HTML5 page which determines whether the device is "Portrait" mode or in "Landscape" .

Below is the code i have alerted the orientation . Sometimes when i turn from landscape to portrait it still alerts as landscape and the co ordinates i check are shown as wrong . 
The test device is Google Nexus

***Tablet Google Nexus 7 
Andriod version 4.2.2 
Chrome App version:35.0.1916.141
OS Andriod 4.4.2;Nexus 7 Build/KOT49H
Javascript version:
V8 3.25.28.18***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageSetter() {
        if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
            // you're in PORTRAIT mode
            alert('Portrait');
        }

        if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
            // you're in LANDSCAPE mode
            alert('LANDSCAPE');
        }
    }
    pageSetter();
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function () {
        pageSetter();
    }, false)

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

window.orientation ==0 refers to the default orientation . Doesnt mean it is in portrait mode. Below link explains in detail.

[Misconception about Window Orientation](http://www.matthewgifford.com/blog/2011/12/22/a-misconception-about-window-orientation/)

Solution is to use Resize instead

[Portrait/Landscape detection](http://pioul.fr/cross-device-cross-browser-portrait-landscape-detection)